# Best practice for storing and using user data with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cookies, jwt

I want your advice on the best practice for storing and reusing user data in my application.

I created two apps:

- the first is an API to recover data
- the second is a Vue.js application for the front-end part

I am using a JWT for authentication.

When I am authenticated, I save two elements in the cookies:

- token
- userId

In the Vue.js application, as long as the token exists in the cookie, the user remains authenticated, the verification is done on each new route for the front-end.
In the back-end each route waits for a valid token.

I want to create a navbar with the name of the person connected at the top right, and their profile photo for example.
This navbar appears on all pages.
For the moment in my "navbar" component I have set up an api request with the userId present in the cookie to retrieve user information.

I don't think it's a good practice to do this on all pages? Perhaps the best will be to store this information directly in cookies to retrieve it more easily?

I'm having trouble knowing what to store and what not to store cookies.
For example I will not store a user object containing its creation date, email address, etc.

Comment: *I don't think it's a good practice to do this on all pages* - it's a good practice, unless proven otherwise. For SPA, a request is done once per session. Cookies are for essential data and shouldn't be used as general purpose cache.

Comment: @BibDev are you saying that you send an API request to retrieve user information every time you navigate to another view?